# PHP Json Parsing 6

Tags: php, json

How do I pull the 76561198216468627 from

```
{ "response": { "steamid": "76561198216468627", "success": 1 } }
```

I've tried this but it pulls 1 instead of the id

```
    foreach ($parsed_json->{'reponse'} as $item) {
$steamid = $item;
}
```

Comment: Your code is iterating over the values of the response property in that parsed json. You want to access the steam ID directly. Do that instead of iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode the JSON string into either a PHP object or array.  Here's how to do it each way:

**ARRAY METHOD**

```
$jsonString = '{ "response": { "steamid": "76561198216468627", "success": 1 } }';
$json = json_decode($jsonString, true);
foreach($json as $item)
{
    $steamid = $item['steamid'];
}
```

**OBJECT METHOD**

```
$jsonString = '{ "response": { "steamid": "76561198216468627", "success": 1 } }';
$json = json_decode($jsonString);
foreach($json as $item)
{
    $steamid = $item->steamid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json = '{
    "response": [{ "steamid": "76561198216468627", "success": 1 }]
}';

$decode = json_decode($json);
echo $decode->response[0]->steamid;
```

Then you can get 76561198216468627